# Fallback Function in Example Crowsale Contract on Ethereum

Tags: solidity

Can anyone explain the fallback function in crowsale contract [here](https://www.ethereum.org/crowdsale).

The part that confuses me is the `msg.value` and `msg.sender`. Who's address does `msg` refer to?

`uint amount = msg.value` seems saying `msg` refers to the address that is contributing to the crowsale. `balanceOf[msg.sender]` seems saying msg refers to the contract address.

Can someone explain? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> `uint amount = msg.value`

This line declares new variable called `amount` and assigns it the value which was sent in `Wei` with transaction.

> `balanceOf[msg.sender]`

`balanceOf` refers to a mapping (it's like key-value array) where as key is contributor to crowdsale and where value is the amount contributor deposited in `Wei`.

Summarizing, when you call function (*sendTransaction*), smart contract has a set of commands which provide information about transaction.

- `msg.sender` is referring to a sender of transaction, normal account address in your case. It can refer to contract address, when inside some function contract is calling another method for example.
- `msg.value` - value, which msg.sender attached with transaction in `Wei` (smallest unit in Ethereum).
- you can refer to contract address by using `this` if needed

[Read more about Transaction Properties](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.19/units-and-global-variables.html?#block-and-transaction-properties)

Comment: Thank you for answering! That is also how I understand it, but the way they used `balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount` confused me. If `msg.sender` refers to the contributing address, isn't `balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount` reading the balance of the contributing address and add the amount back to that address instead of the crowsale contract address?

Comment: Contract receive value (in `Wei`) and store it in `this.balance`. `balanceOf[msg.sender]` reffers to the contributing address. And since `balanceOf` is like array where we store contributor => amount, we want the amount of money they contributed to increase if new contributions come.